# Datetime querystring format when paging the sorted list-view

Tags: 2013, list-view, date-time, sorting, paging

When I sort a column (ExpiryDate) in the list view and then click next page button, SharePoint generates URL like this:

http://www.example.com/Lists/WatchList/AllItems.aspx#InplviewHash0691b043-5378-45ae-b6ba-c6512ae1a061=Paged%3DTRUE-p_ExpiryDate%3D20170305%252018%253a20%253a00-p_ID%3D525-FolderCTID%3D0x012001-SortField%3DExpiryDate-SortDir%3DAsc-PageFirstRow%3D21

I'm wondering what is the date time format that is used in the query string: **p_ExpiryDate%3D20170305%252018%253a20%253a00**

It should be generated from the **ExpiryDate** data of the last item from the previous page: **6/03/2017 2:20 AM**

How can I generate that date time query string value?